# Output project directory cannot be located inside ChilliSource / ...directory already exists

Tags: game-engine

I'm trying to check out Chilli Source but I'm getting errors at first try with cmd. If I make directory there is one error:

```
C:\ChilliSource-master\ChilliSource-master\Tools>java -jar CSProjectGenerator.jar --projectname gra1 --packagename ab.cdef.gra --output ../gra1 --logginglevel verbose
FATAL: Output project directory '../gra1/gra1/' already exists!
0 Warnings found.
1 Errors found.
```

If i delete directory there is another error:

```
C:\ChilliSource-master\ChilliSource-master\Tools>java -jar CSProjectGenerator.jar --projectname gra1 --packagename ab.cdef.gra --output ../gra1 --logginglevel verbose
FATAL: Output project directory '../gra1/gra1/' cannot be located inside Chilli Source.
0 Warnings found.
1 Errors found.
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution: http://forums.chilli-works.com/t/output-project-directory-cannot-be-located-inside-chillisource-directory-already-exists/29/2

---

Just some text to make post at least 30 characters.